# Lua: os.execute("sleep n") in infinite loop can't be stopped by ^C

Tags: lua, signals, posix

In lua 5.2.4, when using the widely used `os.execute('sleep n')` method in an infinite loop, the program can't be stopped by `^C` (Ctrl-C).

Minimal example:

```
while true do
    print("HELLO!")
    os.execute("sleep 3")
end
```

My questions are:

1. Is this expected behavior? I would have guessed the program receives the `^C` signal after returning from the `os.execute` command.
2. Is there a "builtin" way to sleep **efficiently**?

Comment: There is bunch of alternative solution for sleep problem http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Control-c is most probably being caught by the shell spawned by `os.execute`, not by Lua. You need to look at the code returned by `os.execute`. When the command ends normally, `os.execute` returns true,"exit",rc. Otherwise, it returns nil,etc. When it is interrupted with control-c, it returns nil,"signal",2 in my machine.

Bottom line, try this code:

```
while true do
    print("HELLO!")
    if not os.execute("sleep 3") then break end
end
```

Comment: thanks for also solving the actual problem most folks were facing!

Comment: As an aside, that there may not be a child shell at all, at least not for very long.  Most shells optimize simple command string invocation (e.g., `/bin/sh -c 'sleep 3'`) by just execve()ing the simple command, rather than forking and waiting for a child.  This would not change the OP's observed behavior, however.

Answer (score 3):

### Short Answer

Your *sleep* child is killed by the terminal's SIGINT, but `os.execute` ignores the signal and thus *lua* continues in its loop.

### Longer Answer

Your terminal driver turns <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> into a SIGINT generated for the foreground process group, which includes (at least) your *lua* process and its child *sleep* process.

(This signal is overwhelmingly likely to be generated while the *lua* script is inside `os.execute`, since that is where your script spends the majority of its time.)

When that happens, the *sleep* process is killed immediately by SIGINT.  The *lua* process, however, ignores the signal.

It ignores SIGINT because `os.execute` is a wrapper around the traditional library call [`system`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html), as you can see [in the source](https://www.lua.org/source/5.2/loslib.c.html#os_execute):

```
static int os_execute (lua_State *L) {
  const char *cmd = luaL_optstring(L, 1, NULL);
  int stat = system(cmd);      /* <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< here <<<<<<<<<<<<< */
  if (cmd != NULL)
    return luaL_execresult(L, stat);
  else {
    lua_pushboolean(L, stat);  /* true if there is a shell */
    return 1;
  }
}
```

This library call has very specific semantics, including ignoring SIGINT in the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Nice explanations from @pilcrow and @lhf. Based on that info, I just crafted a sleep method, what exits when sleep process is exited prematurely (killed).

```lua
function responsive_sleep(duration)
    local endTime = os.time() + duration
    os.execute("sleep " .. tonumber(duration))
    if os.time() < endTime then
        -- The sleep was interrupted, indicating the process should exit.
        os.exit(125)
    end
end
```